# PySpark Conditional formatting on final DataFrame after joining two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark, group-by

PySpark DataFrame Scenario:

1. There is a DataFrame called `DF`. Two main columns of `DF` are `ID` and `Date`.
2. Each `ID` has on average 40+ unique `Date`s (not continuous dates).
3. Now, there is second DataFrame called `DF_date` which has one column named `Date`. The dates in `Dates` range between maximum and minimum of 'Date' from `DF`.
4. Now, the goal is to fill `DF` with the continuous Start and End date of each unique 'ID' (missing discontinued dates are filled with `left join` between `DF_date` and `DF`.

`DF`

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|         Date|          Val|              ID|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   2021-07-01|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-04|     81289.62|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-05|     81385.62|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-02|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-05|     81324.28|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-06|     81329.28|         Bz3838J|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

`DF_date`

```
+-------------+
|         Date|
+-------------+
|   2021-07-01|
|   2021-07-02|
|   2021-07-03|
|   2021-07-04|
|   2021-07-05|
|   2021-07-06|
+-------------+
```

Expected Final Output:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|         Date|          Val|              ID|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
|   2021-07-01|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-02|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-03|     81119.73|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-04|     81289.62|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-05|     81385.62|         Ax3838J|
|   2021-07-02|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-03|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-04|     81249.76|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-05|     81324.28|         Bz3838J|
|   2021-07-06|     81329.28|         Bz3838J|
+-------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above question, I later realised as suggested @wwnde there is no need to create a separate DF for Dates.

Code provided below serves the purpose too -

```
# Partition the data based on the client and order by DATE
window_fn = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy('DATE')


# the ranges of dates between the DATE value in the current row and the following row 

next_date = F.coalesce(F.lead("DATE", 1).over(window_fn), F.col("DATE") + F.expr("interval 1 day"))

end_date_range = next_date - F.expr("interval 1 day")

# then using 'sequence' function to generate all intermediate dates
# exploded this array to fill in values for the missing dates.

final_result = DF.withColumn("Ranges", F.sequence(F.col("DATE"), end_date_range, F.expr("interval 1 day")))\
  .withColumn("DATE", F.explode("Ranges"))\
  .withColumn("DATE", F.to_timestamp("date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'))\
  .drop("Ranges")

display(final_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. Why have a `DF_date` dataframe with start and end dates, use them to fill in date and then resort to using the `DF` start and end date. Why not just fill in missing dates by using `DF` min and max date for each group.

Anyway, this is how you fill in missing dates based on `DF_Date`

Following your comments, see my edits

```
  new = (DF.groupby('ID')
       .agg(to_date(first('Date')).alias('min_date')#minimum date per group
       ,to_date(last('Date')).alias('max_date')#max date per group
       ,*[collect_list(i).alias(f"{i}") for i in DF.drop('ID').columns])#Dates and Val into an array for each group
       
       #Explosion results into a new column 2 which ideally is the new date, Drop existing date and rename 2 to date
       .selectExpr("ID","inline(arrays_zip(Date,Val,sequence(min_date,max_date,interval 1 day)))")
       .drop('Date').withColumnRenamed('2','Date')
       #Forward fill the Val column
      .withColumn('Val', coalesce(last('val',True).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Date'))))
       
      ).show()

+-------+--------+----------+
|     ID|     Val|      Date|
+-------+--------+----------+
|Ax3838J|81119.73|2021-07-01|
|Ax3838J|81289.62|2021-07-02|
|Ax3838J|81385.62|2021-07-03|
|Ax3838J|81385.62|2021-07-04|
|Ax3838J|81385.62|2021-07-05|
|Bz3838J|81249.76|2021-07-02|
|Bz3838J|81324.28|2021-07-03|
|Bz3838J|81329.28|2021-07-04|
|Bz3838J|81329.28|2021-07-05|
|Bz3838J|81329.28|2021-07-06|
+-------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: You're right, doesn't make sense to use `DF_Date` if we can fill the dates based on start and end date. How can I fill the missing values based on start and end date for each `ID`?

Comment: Did this help? Happy to help further. Let me know

Comment: File "<command-547308747169944>", line 2
    new = (DF.groupby('ID')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: just means that there is space between at the start of your code. Make sure it starts right at the start. Put cursor before `new` and backspace. Let me know

Comment: name 'to_date' is not defined. If I put F.to_date, next 'first' not defined and similarly for last.

Comment: `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` without changing code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243480/discussion-between-sargupta-and-wwnde).

Comment: How did you go?

Comment: It didn't work (maybe due to size of data) but managed to solve the problem. Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: How did you solve so that others benefit?

Comment: Just answered, please have a look. And if you like the approach, please feel free to upvote.